# What does 'pure' in functional programming mean if an application mutates the stack?

Tags: functional-programming, side-effects, purely-functional, mutation, referential-transparency

We know that [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function):

1. Always return the same result for a given input
2. Produce no side-effects

This leads us to [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) - where *an expression can be replaced with a value without changing the behaviour of the program*.

This tells us that a program can be said to be [purely functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional) if it *excludes destructive modifications (updates) of entities in the program's running environment*.

This [commentator wrote](https://twitter.com/alandipert/status/699983290493771777):

> grappling with what "pure" in an FP setting actually means, considering application itself is a protocol for mutation (the stack)

My question is: **What does 'pure' in functional programming mean if an application mutates the stack?**

Comment: The same as would mean if the stack didn't exist? The stack is just an implementation detail and shouldn't matter when defining a 'pure' function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the function mutates the stack is a consequence of the implementation of the machine. It doesn't matter for defining pure, just as the fact that using a 'value' requires mutating a register in the processor core doesn't matter.

If a function doesn't mutate (or depend on) anything external to its own stack frame (e.g. global variables, io, randomness), it can still be viewed as pure.

Comment: Would it be possible to implement a machine that didn't mutate the stack?

Comment: There can certainly be implementations that don't mutate 'the stack' or even have a stack, but I'm fairly sure to have a physical machine that computes something is going to be mutating (I would love to hear that I am wrong though).

Comment: Could you point to such a non-stack mutating machine implementation?

Comment: Does it need to have subroutines? :) I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for, but you might try [the RS08](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freescale_RS08) (which doesn't have a system stack / stack pointer), [stackless python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stackless_Python) (which pretty much still has a stack, it is just in the heap), and [cps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) (which may be implemented using either the system stack or the heap).